# WordPress Theme Move Object with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress-theming

I'm working on http://taxlienagents.com/ and I am trying to take the horizontal blue bar on the bottom that reads "Safe Investments/Higher Returns/Buy Now"  and move it up so it is closer to the "How to," "Coaching," and "Done for You" buttons. When the Buttons are clicked and the window resizes, I want to also move blue bar with the buttons. I've already gotten the site to be as XHTML 1.0 Transitional Compliant as I could and I have tried putting the blue bar into the TAB Div.

Any support would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First.

You need to clear your floats. This is a huge thing you must remember to always to do.

```
<!-- END CONTENT AREA -->

<div style="clear:both;"></div>

<!-- CALL TO ACTION AREA -->
```

Between the end of your content area and the call to action, add a div with a style of 'clear:both'. This will alow your footer to retain structure.

Then, on

```
<div id="call-to-action"></div>
```

You need to remove in the CSS

```
margin-top:755px;
```

Now you will retain the design style that you want.